# How to tell if a directory on a Linux machine has an external file system mounted to it in Java?

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

I have three separate Linux servers that mount and share the same single file system under a directory called /efs

I have a Java application that uses this file system, and needs to be able to verify that the file system has been mounted correctly (Or else, it would simply write to /efs on the local machine instead of the shared storage without knowing) - How would I detect at run time from my application that the file system has been mounted to the directory?

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I really did try to find information on this but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: You need to invoke Linux programs that can tell you.  This makes it a Linux/Unix question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few approaches to this problem:

1. If the mounted filesystem at /efs is different from the root filesystem, you can compare them using `Files.getFileStore(path).type()`. The filesystem for / being the same would then be a clear indicator that the /efs mount is missing. This assumes JDK >= 7.
2. Read and parse `/proc/mounts` to see which file systems are mounted and with which options. This is the same data source Java's FileStore API uses under the hood, so you might take the parsing logic directly from the JDK sources. This would be independent on the Java version.
3. Have a file on the mounted filesystem which is never on the root filesystem which can then be checked for simply by `Files.exists(path)` or `new File(path).exists()`. This would be independent from the Java version and even independent from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - It just occurred to me to create a file in the mounted file system and simply check the file exists avoiding any OS dependent code.